# Generic interface returning Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I would like to have an interface like this:

```
public interface IQuery       // I do NOT want IQuery<T>
{
    Task<T> Result();         // Only this line can change
}
```

Is this possible?

The reason for this change is that having `Query<T>`, the code below worked, however having Task in there makes 'q' null. dynamic stuff no longer works. So to fix that I have to have `IQuery` without constraint.

```
public Action(object obj)
{
    ...
    var q = obj as IQuery<dynamic>; // Having Query<T> q is NULL - bad!
    Query = new Optional<IQuery<dynamic>>(q);
}
```

EDIT:
[image]

EDIT 2:
Is there a way to have IQuery this way:

```
public interface IQuery<T>
{
    Task<T> Result();
}
```

and to make this work?

```
var q = obj as IQuery<dynamic>;
```

whre obj is this class:

```
public class GetReminder : IQuery<ReminderDb>
{

    public override async Task<ReminderDb> Result()
    {
        // read from db and return

        ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the generic constraint (i.e. `<ReminderDb>`) if you will return only a single type

Comment: Yes, but home come I can't return ReminderDb?

Comment: You are creating a generic parameter named the same as the class, and that name takes precedence over the class

Comment: Answers below are correct, however I wanted to do away with having where T : on each every implementation of IQuery. On top of that I wanted to use base Query class. So ended up using Task<dynamic> Result(). This way I'm able to: var q = obj as IQuery; later for other purposes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
public interface IQuery
{
    Task<T> Result<T>();
}
```

Then implemented like:

```
public class GetReminder : IQuery
{
    public async Task<T> Result<T>() where T: ReminderDb, new()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(new T()); // return a new instance
    }
}
```

The `ReminderDb` constraint will limit at compile-time for either `ReminderDb` or any type that implements it, while the `new()` constraint will allow you to use a parameter-less constructor.

You would then call this with:

```
var getReminder = new GetReminder();
var reminderDb = await getReminder.Result<ReminderDb>();
```

Comment: It's not legal to put a constraint on the implementation that's not in the interface! The interface says that `Result` must be able to accept *any T*, so you can't go putting a restriction on it in the implementation; you haven't implemented the interface.

Comment: @EricLippert I first though that, but was surprised that it compiles just fine. Weirdly enough, it doesn't compile if the constraint is put on the interface but not on the class. Why is that?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I tried your code, but visual studio generated an error: "error CS0425: The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'GetReminder.Result<T>()' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'IQuery.Result<T>()'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead."

Comment: @Brian That's weird. I was able to compile this on my home PC yesterday, but I'm not able to on my work PC (same VS 2017 (15.5.2) version)

Comment: While not specified in the question, I would resolve situations like this by defining an empty  `Interface` that `ReminderDb` implements. `interface IReminder {}` `interface IQuery { Task<T> Result<T>() where T: IReminder; }` `class ReminderDb : IReminder{ .. }` Then, can return a `ReminderDb`. DOWNSIDE: Caller must cast returned value to use as a ReminderDB: `var result = (await Result()) as ReminderDb;`.

Answer (score 4):

To the original question:
Yes, you can define your interface without generic parameter and still make it have a method with generic parameter, just as @MegaTron answered.

To your new question put in edit:
You surely can return Task. It's just your method definition goes wrong.
I guess what you want is:

```
public override async Task<T> Result<T>() where T : new() // or T : ReminderDb?
{
    var t = new T();
    // do what you want with t...
}
```

To use the method:

```
var task = resultGenerator.Result<ReminderDb>();
```

You cannot use `ReminderDb` as the name of your generic parameter (that is, you cannot write `public override async Task<ReminderDb> Result<ReminderDb>()`) because as the IDE suggests, that will hide the class `ReminderDb`.

**Edit 1:**
More explanations on my answer to the first edit part of the question:

In C# you can put constraint on the generic parameter you used.
By constraint I mean the `where T : new()` part in my code sample.
As you may guess, the constraint demands that whatever type `T` you will use to call this method, `T` must have the ability to be new-ed (has a public parameterless constructor and is not an abstract class).

The constraint I used is mandatory in your case because in the question the first line of this method news an instance of `T`.
Please imagine that if the constraint is not applied, the compiler has no way to ensure that the type you used to call the method must have the ability to create a new instance via `new T()`.

Another possible constraint you might want here is to directly demand that the generic parameter inherits from `ReminderDb`.
However, as @Camilo Terevinto suggests, if the only possible type (and not its derived types) that will be used with this method is `ReminderDb`, you do not need the generic parameter at all.

Comment: While a good answer, it would be great if you explain the generic constraint and mention that it's not needed if `ReminderDb` is the only wanted class

Answer (score 3):

Possible but in this way

```
public interface IQuery     // I do NOT want IQuery<T>
{
    Task<T> Result<T>(); // Only this line can change
}
```

Comment: Please see edit. I can't create that type within Result() method. why? ReminderDb is simple class. I want to be able to get ReminderDb from Database or create a new one and Result() method should return it.